# where to add a column with low cardinality, decimal type into an index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I got a question regarding the best way to put a **bad column for an index** in an index, so that I can satisfy my query below, and similar others that follow the same pattern.

on the query below, 
all the columns in the select come from table **TableBackups.[dbo].[tblBOrderItem]**.

I only go to the other table - **TableBackups.[dbo].[tblBOrder]** - to get the orders that are between the @fromDate and @todate
**AND** the order must have a value 
which in my system here it translates to

**i.decCatItemPrice > 0**

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON 

DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '27 feb 2016'
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = '28 feb 2016'

    SELECT  i.[strBxOrderNo] ,
            [sintOrderSeqNo] ,
            [sintOrderItemStatusId] ,
            [decBCTaxAmount] ,
            [decBCFinalPrice] ,
            [decBCOverrideDiscount] ,
            [decBCOfferDiscount] ,
            [decBCCatItemPrice] ,
            [decBCCostPrice] ,
            [decTaxAmount] ,
            [decFinalPrice] ,
            [decOverrideDiscount] ,
            [decOfferDiscount] ,
            [decCatItemPrice] ,
            [decCostPrice] ,
            [decWasPrice] ,
            [dtmOrdItemCreated] ,
            [sintOrderItemType] ,
            [strItemNo] ,
            [sintQuantity] ,
            [blnChargeShipping] ,
            i.[strBxOrderNo] + '_' + 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), i.[sintOrderSeqNo]) AS OrderNoItemSeqNo
    FROM    TableBackups.[dbo].[tblBOrderItem] i


    where exists ( select * from TableBackups.[dbo].[tblBOrder] o
                   where o.[sdtmOrdCreated] >= @FromDate
                    AND o.[sdtmOrdCreated] < @ToDate
                    AND i.[strBxOrderNo] = o.[strBxOrderNo]
                    AND i.decCatItemPrice > 0
                 )
```

the primary key of table TableBackups.[dbo].[tblBOrder] is:

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblBorder] 
 ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_tblBOrder] 
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [strBxOrderNo] ASC  )  
  WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF ,
          FILLFACTOR = 95  ,
          SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , 
          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF , 
          STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF , 
          ONLINE = OFF , 
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON , 
          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  ) ON [PRIMARY ]
```

the primary key of table TableBackups.[dbo].[tblBOrderItem] is:

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblBorderItem] 
 ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_tblBOrderItem] 
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [strBxOrderNo] ASC  , 
                          [sintOrderSeqNo] ASC  )   
WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF ,
        FILLFACTOR = 95  ,
        SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF , 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF , 
        ONLINE = OFF , 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON , 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  ) 
        ON [PRIMARY ]
```

when I run the following command to get the data types in table tblBorderItem:

```
sp_help 'tblBorderItem'
```

[image]

there are no foreign keys connection the item tables to the order table.
although the column strBxOrderNo varchar(20) is on the primary key of both tables.

```
sp_help 'tblBorder'
```

[image]

this is the index I have created to improve the performance of this query:

```
    -- THE NEW INDEX - FILTERED
      CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
IX_tblBOrderItem_decCatItemPrice_INCL 
ON [dbo].[tblBorderItem] (  [decCatItemPrice] , 
                            [strBxOrderNo] , 
                            [strItemNo] )   
     INCLUDE ( [blnChargeShipping] , 
     [decBCCatItemPrice] , 
     [decBCCostPrice] , 
     [decBCFinalPrice] , 
     [decBCOfferDiscount] , 
     [decBCOverrideDiscount] , 
     [decBCTaxAmount] , 
     [decCostPrice] , 
     [decFinalPrice] , 
     [decOfferDiscount] , 
     [decOverrideDiscount] , 
     [decTaxAmount] , 
     [decWasPrice] , 
     [dtmOrdItemCreated] , 
     [sintOrderItemStatusId] , 
     [sintOrderItemType] , 
     [sintOrderSeqNo] , 
     [sintQuantity] )
     WHERE [decCatItemPrice]  > 0
     WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF ,
             FILLFACTOR = 95 ,
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , 
             IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF ,
             STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF , 
             ONLINE = OFF , 
             DROP_EXISTING = ON , 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON , 
             ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  )
```

the questions:

1) [decCatItemPrice] is better off as an index column or as a column in the INCLUDE? how do you decide?

I have taken my decisions through try and error, and this index arrangement is the one that reduced the **logical reads** number to the lowest as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

2) I also have the reverse query (all columns come from the order table) but I still need to get ONLY the orders which have **i.decCatItemPrice > 0**
would the same index work for both?

Comment: Why is the `[strItemNo]` in the index? It's not used in the query. And have you tried a simple index on `(decCatItemPrice)`? It's equivalent I think to the composite `(decCatItemPrice, strBxOrderNo)` in this case, due to the choice of the CI.

Comment: But really, much depends on distribution. What percent of the table rows have a positive value in that `decCatItemPrice` column? If it's not a very small percentage, then a full table scan may be unavoidable (and better)!

Comment: If the percentage is very small (or in other words, if the condition `decCatItemPrice > 0` does reduce the amount of returned rows by a large factor) then a simpler and smaller index on `(PK columns) WHERE (decCatItemPrice > 0)` might be better than the much wider index you have made.